# AcrUserDialogs Toast Position Xamarin Forms UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin Forms 4.1 solution with Android, iOS and UWP projects that I am using Acr.UserDialogs. For the most part everything works as it should with the dialogs and toasts except for UWP. It works in UWP but the Toast messages display in the upper left hand corner which covers the menu button. I need the toast to display at the bottom of the screen in UWP just as it does for Android and iOS. Can someone help me with correcting this issue?

Here is my code as to how I display the toast:

```
                var toastConfig = new ToastConfig(toastMsg);
                toastConfig.SetDuration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));
                toastConfig.SetPosition(ToastPosition.Bottom);
                UserDialogs.Instance.Toast(toastConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [`AcrUserDialogs`](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/master/src/Acr.UserDialogs/Platforms/Uwp/UserDialogsImpl.cs#L267), This library realize toast with [`ToastPrompt`](https://github.com/Coding4FunProjects/Coding4FunToolkit/blob/master/source/Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls/Prompts/ToastPrompt.cs), Unfortunately, it does not support for setting position. So `SetPosition` does not available in UWP platform.

```
public override IDisposable Toast(ToastConfig config)
        {
            ToastPrompt toast = null;

            return this.DispatchAndDispose(
                () =>
                {
                    toast = new ToastPrompt
                    {
                        Message = config.Message,
                        //Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
                        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWholeWords,
                        MillisecondsUntilHidden = Convert.ToInt32(config.Duration.TotalMilliseconds)
                    };
                    if (config.Icon != null)
                        toast.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(config.Icon));

                    if (config.MessageTextColor != null)
                        toast.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(config.MessageTextColor.Value.ToNative());

                    if (config.BackgroundColor != null)
                        toast.Background = new SolidColorBrush(config.BackgroundColor.Value.ToNative());

                    toast.Show();
                },
                () => toast.Hide()
            );
        }
```